# How to generate date::local_time from std::chrono_time_point

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono

I'm using Howard Hinnant's time zone library.

https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

My question: Is it possible to construct a date::local_time object from a std::chrono::time_point?

What I want to to:

```
// 'tp' exists and is some std::chrono::time_point object 
auto locTime = date::local_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tp);
```

The constructor for this doesn't exist so a get a compilation error.
How do I do this (in nice and clean C++17)?

Background:
My ultimate goal is to compare a `std::filesystem::file_time_type` to a `date::local_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>`.

I do

`auto fileTimeTp = std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(someDirectoryEntryObject.last_write_time());`

which gives my my std::chrono::time_point for the file date, but that's where I'm stuck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a two part answer ...

### Part 1

> My question: Is it possible to construct a date::local_time object from a `std::chrono::time_point`?

I'm going to assume that `std::chrono::time_point` refers to `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` (each clock has its own family of `std::chrono::time_point`).

Yes, it is possible.  Background:  `system_clock::time_point` is defined as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is a close approximation to UTC.  So to go from `system_clock::time_point` (also know as `sys_time` in the date library / C++20) to `local_time`, you need to pair the `sys_time` with a `time_zone`.  This could be your computer's current local time zone, or any other [IANA time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

To get the computer's current local time zone:

```
auto tz = date::current_zone();
```

The type of `tz` is a `date::time_zone const*`.  `time_zone` has a member function called `to_local` that will translate a `sys_time` into a `local_time`:

```
auto locTime = tz->to_local(system_clock::now());
```

The precision of `locTime` will match whatever the precision of the input `sys_time` is.

If you would like to use some other time zone, then you can use `date::locate_zone` to get a `date::time_zone const*` to *that* time zone.

```
auto locTime = date::locate_zone("America/New_York")->to_local(system_clock::now());
```

### Part 2

> My ultimate goal is to compare a `std::filesystem::file_time_type` to a `date::local_time<std::chrono::milliseconds>`.

Ah, this won't really involve `local_time` at all.  And unfortunately, `file_clock` is not implemented in [the time_zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).

In C++20, this will be quite easy:  Given a `file_time` and a `sys_time` you can convert either to the other using `clock_cast`:

```
if (clock_cast<system_clock>(ftp) >= system_clock::now())
    ...
```

However in C++17 it is harder, and non-portable.  The [the time_zone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) makes it easier, but not easy.

You first have to deduce the epoch of `std::filesystem::file_time_type` on your platform.  This will be different depending on which implementation of `std::filesystem::file_time_type` you are using.

Existing epochs include:

```
* 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
* 1601-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
* 2174-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

Then you subtract the `sys_time` epoch (`sys_days{1970_y/1/1}`) and the `file_time` epoch (e.g. `sys_days{1601_y/1/1}`), and add/subtract that epoch to convert from one measure to the other.

For example:

```
constexpr auto diff = sys_days{1970_y/1/1} - sys_days{1601_y/1/1};
file_time_type ftp = ...
system_clock::time_point tp{ftp.time_since_epoch() - diff};
```

That's unfortunately quite messy, and I'm looking forward to `clock_cast` working with `file_clock` in C++20.

Comment: Thanks!  I think you meant `auto locTime = tz->to_local(system_clock::now());
` instead of `auto locTime = tz->local_time(system_clock::now());` but it works this way.